# Universal Google Analytics Multiple Domains

Tags: google-analytics

From my understanding, Google Analytics Universal tracking code should track data from any domain, or sub domain if you place the script on the page.

So with my code:

```
> <script>  
> (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
> (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new
> Date();a=s.createElement(o),  
> m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
> })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
> 
>   ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'domain-example.com');   ga('send',
> 'pageview');
> 
> </script>
```

Which was originally created for "example1.domain-example.com" subdomain.

I have requested that this also be put into "example2.domain-example.com"

However, am only receiving data from "example1".

Am I missing something here?

Do I not have the right GA code in place?

Comment: You should be seeing data from example2. Do you have any filters on the profile you're viewing data from?